# Need help translating those two Cypher queries into Traversal Framework

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, graph-traversal

The first one is as follows: given a sequence of properties that specify a path, I should return the the end node. i.e.

```
start r=node(0)
match r<-[:R]-({n:"aaa"})<-[:R]-({n:"bbb"})<-[:R]-(x {n:"ccc"})
    return x as node
```

And the second one is kind of opposite: given a node's identifier (for simplicity suppose it is the node's ID), return the path (sequence of properties `name`) from the root to the node (it's guaranteed to be unique). As for now, I'm just using the `shortestPath`:

```
start n=node(1000), root = node(0) 
match p = shortestPath(root<-[:R*]-n) 
return
    reduce(fullpath = '', pt IN nodes(p) | fullpath + pt.n)
    as path
```

The queries are run from embedded database and aren't satisfying me with their speed, so I'd like to have them translated into  `TraversalDescription`s, but they should change dynamically, and I don't quite understand how to do this.

Or maybe these queries aren't optimal? The one with the `shortestPath` runs for <= 1ms, while the one with variable length runs for 10ms per single query (that's unacceptable). Maybe you have some performance tips for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following.  The idea is to traverse but only continue to expand down the path if the properties of the current node match the sequence of values.  I haven't tested the code below, so assume typos and missing ;

```
Node r = db.getNodeById(0);
String[] sequence = {"aaa","bbb","ccc"};

Traverser traverser = Traversal.description()
                .depthFirst()
                .expand(new ArrayExpander(sequence))
                .evaluator(Evaluators.atDepth(sequence.length()))
                .uniqueness(Uniqueness.NONE)
                .traverse(r);

for ( org.neo4j.graphdb.Path p : traverser )
        {
            //do something with the nodes accessible by p.nodes()
        }
```

The path expander looks something like:

```
public class ArrayExpander implements PathExpander {

private String[] sequence;

public ArrayExpander(String[] sequence)
{
    this.sequence = sequence;
}

public Iterable<Relationship> expand(Path path, BranchState state){
    if(path.endNode().getProperty("n").equals(sequence[path.length()]){
      return path.endNode().getRelationships(Direction.INCOMING);
    } else {
      return path.endNode().getRelationships(DynamicRelationshipType.withName("IDONTEXIST"));
     }

}

public ArrayExpander reverse()
{
    return new ArrayExpander(Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(sequence)));
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Max, that really helped. The changes are even more significant than I expected. So, here's the actual piece of code I'm using now: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6796366/. My observations are: 1) breadth-first search runs twice as long as depth-search; 2) instead of returning nonexistent relationships, it's better to return an empty list, which is singleton over JVM, hence doesn't lead to creation of new objects, which can be painful on long paths; 3) this  example of expanders usage is just awesome - they should have it in docs already! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Ah, about the speed. Before: 100 traversals per second, after: 8000 traversal per second.